# Apache Flink : How to set time to live in Cassandra sink?

Tags: cassandra, apache-flink, ttl

I am saving POJO thru Cassandra apache Sink.

How to set "Time To Live" in this Cassandra sink?

Regards,
Ali

Answer (score 2):

Here is my answer:

```
    // Write to cassandra
CassandraSink.addSink(metricPredictions)
        .setClusterBuilder(new ClusterBuilder() {
            @Override
            protected Cluster buildCluster(Cluster.Builder b) {
                return b.addContactPoint((String) CASSANDRA_MAP.get(PropertiesEnum.HOST.getKey()))
                        .withPort((int) CASSANDRA_MAP.get(PropertiesEnum.PORT.getKey()))
                        .withAuthProvider(new PlainTextAuthProvider((String) CASSANDRA_MAP.get(PropertiesEnum.USERNAME.getKey()),
                                (String) CASSANDRA_MAP.get(PropertiesEnum.PASSWORD.getKey())))
                        .withReconnectionPolicy(new ConstantReconnectionPolicy((Integer) CASSANDRA_MAP.get(PropertiesEnum.RECONNECT_DELAY_IN_MS.getKey())))

                        .build();
            }
        })
        .setMapperOptions(() -> new Mapper.Option[]{Mapper.Option.saveNullFields(true), Mapper.Option.ttl(60)})
        .build()
        .setParallelism((int) CASSANDRA_MAP.get(PropertiesEnum.PARALLELISM.getKey()));
```

I hope it will help :)

By the way TTL is in seconds.

Regards,
Ali